# Using Taylor series to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sqrt{1+ x\sin(x)} - \sqrt{\cos(2x)}}{ \tan^2(x/2)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

To be honest, I have to solve the following exercise, but I don't know what trigonometric formulas should I use (if I should), to get to a form where I can use the Taylor series.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+ x\sin(x)} - \sqrt{\cos(2x)}}{ \tan^2(x/2)}$$

I have tried to convert the tan function (using trig formulas) but it didn't work, also I tried to use Taylor series on the $\sin(x), \cos(2x)$ functions.

Comment: What steps did you try? If you know that $\sin x \approx x, \cos x \approx 1$ (ignore the $-x^2/2$ term), you can approximate $\tan x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed we don't need Taylor's series in this case but if we want to proceed by this way we have that

- $x\sin x=x^2+O(x^3) \implies \sqrt{1+ x\sin(x)}=1+\frac12 x^2+O(x^3)$
- $\cos(2x)=1-2x^2 +O(x^3) \implies \sqrt{\cos(2x)}=1-x^2+O(x^3)$
- $\tan^2(x/2)=\frac14 x^2+O(x^3)$

and therefore

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+ x\sin(x)} - \sqrt{\cos(2x)}}{ \tan^2(x/2)}=$$

$$=\frac{1+\frac12 x^2-1+x^2+O(x^3)}{\frac14 x^2+O(x^3)}=\frac{\frac32 x^2+O(x^3)}{\frac14 x^2+O(x^3)}=\frac{\frac32+O(x)}{\frac14 + O(x)} \to 6$$

Comment: The numerator must be $\frac 32 x^2 + O(x^3)$ :)

Comment: @DatBoi Yes of course! I fix the typo. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I must have made a mistake, while doing Taylor on the functions...

Comment: @samivagyok You are welcome! I've jumped some step but you should succed to reconstruct the whole process. Pay attention to the use of little-o or Big-O notation for teh reminder, it is necessary you use that till the end before to take the limit. Bye

Answer (score 2):

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{{\sqrt{1+ x\sin(x)}} - \sqrt{\cos(2x)}}{\tan^2(x/2)}$$

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{{1+ x\sin(x)} - \cos(2x)}{\tan^2(x/2)\Bigg({\sqrt{1+ x\sin(x)}} + \sqrt{\cos(2x)}\Bigg)}$$

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{{ x\sin(x)} + 2\sin^2x}{\tan^2(x/2)\Bigg({\sqrt{1+ x\sin(x)}} + \sqrt{\cos(2x)}\Bigg)}$$

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{{ \frac{\sin(x)}{x}} + 2.\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}}{\frac14.\frac{\tan^2(x/2)}{(x/2)^2}\Bigg({\sqrt{1+ x\sin(x)}} + \sqrt{\cos(2x)}\Bigg)}\ \text{Dividing $N^r$ and $D^r$ by $x^2$}$$

Now use $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$ and $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\tan t}{t}=1$ to obtain
$$\boxed{L=6}$$

Comment: Thank you, even tho my instruction was to use the Taylor series, it was really interesting to see it solved in another way. I have thought about using conjugation like you did, but I thought I would just overcomplicate things. Turns out If I'd be more creative while using the formulas, it wouldn't be that complicated. :)

Comment: @samivagyok Yes. Always consider Taylor expansion the last approach(If you are free to use any method). It involves many numbers and sometimes complicates things.Refer the other answers that have been given which use Taylor series. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

When $z$ is small,
$\sin z =z+..$, $\cos z=1-z^2/2$, $\tan z=z+...$
Then $$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x \sin x}-\sqrt{\cos 2x}}{\tan^2(x/2)}= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1-2x^2}}{x^2/4}$$
Use binomial approximation that $(1+z)^k=1+kz$ if $z$ is very small, then
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x^2/2)-(1-x^2)}{x^2/4}=6.$$

Comment: Why don't you continue with Taylor ? $\sqrt{1+ax^2}\to 1+\dfrac{ax^2}2$ ?

Comment: Thank you, even tho my instruction was to use the Taylor series, it was really interesting to see it solved in another way.

Comment: @ZAhmed That's fine but as a suggestion, we should include the remainder terms in the final step, in general this way to proceed can lead to erroneous evaluation.

Comment: Once you see $x^2$ in the numerator, expanding terms in denominator complete up to $x^2$, is sufficient for the correct result.

Comment: @ZAhmed Your solution is fine and correct and I'm sure you a have a full control of what is going on but in my opinion it is not good to present a resolution via Taylor's series whitout using remainder terms, even if the notation appears worst. This can lead to great mistakes especially by newcomers.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments of the two square roots will expand as $1$ and a quadratic term ($x^2$ and $-2x^2$ respectively), and the square roots will halve those quadratic terms. The $1$'s cancel out and the quadratic terms end-up as $\dfrac{3x^2}2$.

The denominator is approximated by $\dfrac{x^2}4$, and finally the ratio tends to the finite limit $$6.$$

Comment: That's nice but very difficult to understand and make it profitable by a necomer!

Comment: @user: there are sufficiently many other "classical" answers. I am trying a different style. Who knows... ?

Comment: Yes indeed I appreciate the style and I think this add something useful to the whole. Bye